# exporting variables from shell script to awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am exporting variables from shell script to awk. The program is below

```
export name="hi"
eval $(awk '{element="bye";name=element"name";print name}')
echo $name
```

What is my expected output is I need to concatenate the name with element inside the awk script and then display the concatenated result outside and hence my output would be

name=byehi

But I am not getting the same. Could you ppl please help me regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign variables with the -v option without the need to export anything to the environment. For example:

```
name='hi'
name=$(
    awk -v name="$name" 'BEGIN {print "bye" name}'
)
echo "$name"
```

This will return `byehi` as expected.